Disable macOS mute/unmute mic sound with AirPods
I recently switched to using Zoom with my AirPod Max and notice when I go on/off mute, I get a chime sound similar what was introduced in the iOS 15 or 16 days in the call app on my iPhone. Is there a way to turn that off?
